# DataImageUrlFormatString property Not working

Tags: asp.net, gridview, imagefield

I am working on old Asp .NET GridView Image Field

this is My Sample Code

```
 <asp:GridView>
<Columns> 
<asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="Camera" DataImageUrlFormatString= "test.aspx?ImageID={0}" />
</Columns>
  </asp:GridView>
```

I got this code from one reference but DataImageUrlFormatString property is not working to redirect

On googling , I found value of Property like this

```
dataimageurlformatstring="~\Images\{0}.jpg"
```

...other code I found is used by itemtemplate

```
<asp:templatefield>
    <itemtemplate>
        <asp:image id="Image1" runat="server" imageurl='<%# String.Format("~/{0}/{1}", Eval("dirname"), Eval("filename")) %>' />
    </itemtemplate>
</asp:templatefield>
```

But I want to use asp:ImageField

How that property can be use to Page redirect .OR do I need to work with c# Code to redirect ?

---

Solved

this is working

```
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" Width="100%" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                Font-Names="Arial">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <a href="DiscriptionPurchase.aspx?ProductID=<%#Eval("Id")%>">
                                <asp:Image ID="Camera" Height="100" Width="100" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("Camera")%>'  />
                            </a>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

this is table

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may take the image in anchor tag and provide the redirect URL in anchor tag as mentioned below

```
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <a href="test.aspx?ImageID=<%#Eval("ImageId")%>">
                            <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='ImageURL' /></a>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
```

Comment: How can I assign Parameter(ImageID) with URL

Comment: @NeerajVerma from where you fetching your Image?

Comment: from database column , which contain image Path from Image Folder ,,Like here "Camera" is a column which contain path of camera images in image folder

Comment: So i need to use c# , there is no alternative

Comment: Cant be it done with eval or bind ,, like <a href="test.aspx?ImageID="+Eval("")>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102591/discussion-between-navy-and-neeraj-verma).

Comment: Yes , that eval is the solution  , I added extra "+" in string